# SSH key unprotected terraform ansible jenkins

Tags: ssh, ansible, gitlab, terraform

I have a gitlab repository which contains my ansible and terraform code to dpeloy my infrastructure. (CI/CD)
I stored my ssh keys in my gitlab.
When my jenkins  agent test the ssh connection it works fine. However, when it launches the "ansible-playbook" command, the connection cannot be established because of this error:

```
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0mConnecting to remote host via SSH...
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  Host: ip address
> [0m[1.google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  User: devops
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  Password: false
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  Private key: true
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  Certificate: false
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  SSH Agent: false
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  Checking Host Key: false
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0m  Target Platform: unix
> [0m[1google_compute_instance.instance
> (remote-exec):[0m [0mConnected!

[0m[1google_compute_instance.instance (local-exec):[0m [0mfatal:  UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added  (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\n@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @\r\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\r\nPermissions 0644 for Ansible/lab_ssh_key' are too open.\r\nIt is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.\r\nThis private key will be ignored.\r\nLoad key \"/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Ansible/lab_ssh_key\": bad permissions\r\n Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}

[0m[1google_compute_instance.instance (local-exec):[0m [0mPLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
[0m[1google_compute_instance.instance (local-exec):[0m [0m              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I didnt find a way to secure my private key on gitlab. I tried change its permissions with chmod but after that I couldn't upload it on gitlab.
Any solutions or other thoughts about this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you injecting the SSH key into the CI build?

Comment: To expand on the above, the SSH key should probably be stored as a credential somewhere (inside Jenkins, Vault, etc), and then retrieved with Jenkins plugin bindings. Then you can inject it into Ansible and Terraform easily within Jenkins Pipeline code. Also if you are executing Ansible inside a Terraform config and not within a pipeline, then you will probably find it easier to do so in a `null_resource` and not a `provisioner` `remote-exec`.

Comment: My key is stored in my repo as a file. Thank you for your answer, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is:

- I stored the key in jenkins. (credentials section)
- Then I retrieved it in the jenkins file using the "withcredentials" command. After that I proceed to copy the key in my gitlab.